# "Что только люди (не|ни) придумывают?"

Tags: грамотная-речь, не-или-ни

С ребятами зашла дискуссия, было приведено много аргументов. Нашёл ответ https://touch.otvet.mail.ru/question/39970458 но один из экспертов не согласился. Хочется докопаться до истины. Сам я двоешник по русскому.) Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Правильно: **Что только люди не придумывают!**

Розенталь

5. В самостоятельных **восклицательных и вопросительных предложениях** (часто со словами только, уж) употребляется частица не, а в придаточных частях **сложноподчиненного** предложения (с уступительным оттенком значения) — частица ни. Ср.:

Куда только он не обращался! (‘обращался во многие места’)
Куда только он ни обращался, везде встречал сочувственное отношение.

Что мать не делала для больного сына!
Чего мать ни делала для больного сына, как ни пыталась помочь ему, но спасти его не смогла.

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=82#pp82

**Пояснение**

Простые восклицательные предложения с частицей НЕ имеют **риторическое значение,** при этом заключённое в них отрицание фактически имеет значение **скрытого утверждения.**

*Наш брат охотник куда не заходит!  Кто только не бывал у Горького!  Как не любить родной Москвы! Ну как не порадеть родному человечку!*

Сложность различения  вариантов с НЕ и НИ заключается в том, что разные по форме синтаксические конструкции – **простое восклицательное предложение с НЕ и сложноподчиненное предложение с   НИ** – передают УТВЕРДИТЕЛЬНЫЙ СМЫСЛ СООБЩЕНИЯ.

**Примечание**

Речь идет только о СПП с придаточными **уступительными**.

Сравнить: *И тот не писатель, кто **не прибавил** к зрению человека хотя бы немного зоркости.*

**Частица НЕ** в придаточном **местоименно-определительном.**

Answer (score 4):

*Что только люди **не** придумывают!*

1. Отрицательная частица НЕ пишется в восклицательных или вопросительных предложениях, подразумевающих утвердительный ответ (заменить союзом И или просто опустить частицу здесь невозможно):
   *Где он только НЕ бывал!* = везде бывал.
   *Кто НЕ проклинал станционных смотрителей, кто с ними НЕ бранивался* = все проклинали, все бранивались.
   *Что только люди **не** придумывают!* = много чего придумывают.
2. В  независимых восклицательных и вопросительных предложениях (часто со словами *только, уж*) пишется отрицательная частица **не**.
   Что мать не делала для больного сына! (много делала)

[НЕ или НИ?](http://www.hi-edu.ru/CentrDovusBooks/Intensive/47.pdf)
[Правописание НЕ и НИ](https://books.google.ee/books?id=VY2LAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=%D0%92%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85%20(%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE,%20%D1%83%D0%B6)%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=bZ3vghOajj&sig=AyfFLy02b-ZQbNh3aTXhhuKg-Cg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnvsi33uHfAhXNhaYKHaTIDsEQ6AEwCXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85%20(%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%83%D0%B6)%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5&f=false) (Розенталь)

*Что только **не** придумывают телефонные мошенники, чтобы добраться до ваших банковских карт!* ("Комсомольская правда"); *Чего только **не** придумают…* (сказка Андерсена).

Answer (score 2):

**Что только люди *не* придумывают** - это единственно правильный вариант. Написание с НИ - грубая ошибка (к сожалению, весьма распространенная).

См. также:

Где я только **не** был, чего я **не** отведал -

Берёзовую кашу, крапиву, лебеду,

Только вот на небе я ни разу не обедал,

Господи, прости меня, я с этим обожду.

---

Но сравните: **Что бы люди *ни* придумывали, это уже было.**